# Why sporadic 'Timed out errors' using Indy are not solved until restarting the PC?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I use Indy components in a client app created with Rad Studio Rio to call several web services. This client app is running under Windows Server 2012 in an Azure VM. Sporadically I get "timed out" error in POST and GET functions, calling an external web server using SSL.

The log of this external server shows nothing about these calls. Also, I know that the server is working fine because if I call it from PostMan or from CURL, it works fine.

The weird thing is that after calling the services using CURL, the client app works fine again for some minutes or hours.

Restarting the client app does not affect, the timed out errors appears.

Restarting the PC, it seems that then it works fine for several days.

This client app does thousands of calls every month, but maybe less than 1000 per hour.

Is it possible that Indy spends some kind of Windows resources and then we need to restart the PC to work fine again?

Restarting the app does not solve the problem, only restarting the PC.

We cannot install an sniffer since this is a production machine and there are other processes working.

Comment: Can try [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) on the client and the server to help troubleshoot if it is [port exhaustion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-port-exhaust) or some other connection issue to start with. Otherwise show some code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. It is a port exhaustion issue. I had no idea about this thing. Thanks a lot, I wasted a lot of days in this issue and you saved me a lot of days more!!

Comment: Port exhaustion would not cause timeout errors. Something else is going on. Probably an issue with your PC or your network.

Comment: After restarting the PC, now it is working fine for several days. When it starts to fail, I will do some checks about port exhaustion and other options and I will post it. As a note, the timed out error is always after 27 seconds, and I do not have this value in any place of the app.

Comment: @kokokok "*the timed out error is always after 27 seconds, and I do not have this value in any place of the app*" - you might not, but Indy does. On Windows Vista+, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` internally assigns socket timeouts of 30secs if its `ReadTimeOut` property is `<= 0` (which it is by default).  If you don't want it to do that, set your own `ReadTimeout` value.